# Maplace.js Google Map wont display on the bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched many times for the answer to my question and all the ones I got did not help.

Here is the scenario. I have field data with lat/long in MySQL db. I query the db using Jquery  Ajax via php. The resulting data is displayed by clicking ERFs in the main menu which then present the data in two Bootstrap tabs. One Tab presents the data in tabular form and the other Tab shows the map. See code below.

My problem is, the map just does not show. In fact, the Map tab does not work at all. Can anyone help?

I use Bootstrap, JQuery and AJAX.

I get this error from the console : "InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama". Not sure what this means?

```js
 <script>
  function displayErfsTable(erfArray) {
   $("#erfTable").append("<thead>");
    $("#erfTable").append("<tr>");
    $("#erfTable").append("<th>ERF No</th>");
    $("#erfTable").append("<th>area Name</th>");
    $("#erfTable").append("<th>lat</th>");
    $("#erfTable").append("<th>long</th>"); 
    $("#erfTable").append("</tr>"); 
   $("#erfTable").append("</thead>");
      // Display each row in the ERFs Table 
      for( i = 0; i < erfArray.length; i++ ) {
       var  erfRow = erfArray[i];
      $("#erfTable").append("<tr>");
        $("#erfTable").append("<td> " + erfRow['erf_no'] + " </td>");
        $("#erfTable").append("<td> " + erfRow['an'] + " </td>");
        $("#erfTable").append("<td> " + erfRow['latitude'] + " </td>");          
        $("#erfTable").append("<td> " + erfRow['longitude'] + " </td>");     
    $("#erfTable").append("</tr>");
   }
   //
   $("#erfTable").append("<thead>");
    $("#erfTable").append("<tr>");
     $("#erfTable").append("<th>ERF No</th>");
     $("#erfTable").append("<th>area Name</th>");
     $("#erfTable").append("<th>lat</th>");
     $("#erfTable").append("<th>long</th>"); 
    $("#erfTable").append("</tr>"); 
   $("#erfTable").append("</thead>"); 
  }

  function displayErfsMap(erfArray) {
   $(function() {
    debugger;
    //console.log(map);
       new Maplace({
               map_div:'#map_canvas',
               show_markers: false,
               locations:[{
                   lat: -31.069914,
                   lon: 28.35298,
                   html:'ERF1',
                   zoom:16
               }]
           }).Load();   
   });
  }
 </script>
  
   <script type="text/javascript">
  var i;
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#id_erf_main_menu").click(function (e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
     url: "jq_erf_dbquery.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
     dataType:"json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
     //data:myData, //Form variables
     success:function(erfArray){
      //Display ERFS Table
      displayErfsTable(erfArray);
      //console.log(erfArray);
      displayErfsMap(erfArray);
     },
    });
   });
  }); 
 </script>
```

```css
 <style>
  #mapcanvas {
      width: 100%; 
      height: 500px;
  }
 </style>
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="main_menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="min-height: 0;">
   <!-- Main Menu -->
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#municipalities">Municipalities</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contracotrs">Contractors</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fws">Field Workers</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#devices">Devices</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#erfs" id="id_erf_main_menu">ERFs</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#wos">Works Orders</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#assets">Assets</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav><!-- Main Menu --> 
 </div>

 <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="municipalities" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   <p>Municipalities Windows</p>
  </div>
  <div id="contracotrs" class="tab-pane fade">
   <p>Contractors Windows</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fws" class="tab-pane fade">
   <p>Field Workers Windows</p>
  </div>
  <div id="devices" class="tab-pane fade">
   <p>Devices Windows</p>
  </div>
  <div id="wos" class="tab-pane fade ">
   <p>WOs  goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dashboard" class="tab-pane fade">
   <p>Dashboard data displays here.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="assets" class="tab-pane fade">
   <p>Assets data displays here.</p>
  </div>    
  <div id="erfs" class="tab-pane fade" >
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="erfTab">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">ERF Table</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">ERF Map</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p> ERF Table tab </p>
              <table id="erfTable" class="table table-striped" >
              </table>
      </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
    <p> ERF Map tab </p>
    <div id="mapcanvas"></div>      
   </div>      
  </div>
 </div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the answer. In fact the solution was provided earlier in some of the responses. Just did not look properly. My apologies.

I only had to include "data-toggle="tab" in the

. See below

```html
------------------------------------------------------------------
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" id="erfTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">ERF Table</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">ERF Map</a></li>
</ul>
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My new problem now is, the Maplace Google Map does is not loading. I have included the "maplace.min.js" file and can see in the developer console that it was accessed. But the map is still not loading.

Can anyone give a shot here for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. Again I found the answer to Maplace Google Map not loading.

It had to do with the div map container. I had named my map container div "mapcanvas". For one reason or another, this was where the problem was. I changed the div name to default name used in Maplace.js ("gmap") and suddenly it worked.

What is inreresting is that, when I changed back to "mapcanvas", it continued to work.

Can someone explain this please?

The new problem now is, the map is not drawing properly and is not centered. I must fix that now. Lets go.....